# How do I correctly include plotly types in angular (via local version)

Tags: angular, plotly.js

I managed to have a look at different plotly packages and found out that the angular-plotly pacakge is not really updated anymore.

I chose to include the plotly library by downloading the plotly.min.js file and adding it to my sources. Also, I included this file in my angular.json like this:

```
"scripts": [
                        "src/assets/scripts/plotly.min.js"
                    ]
```

This is a working verison **under the premise that I disable noImplicitAny** in tsconfig.json like this:

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

How do I get to use an @types/plotly.js definition? Other option, am I doing this fundamentally wrong?

---

This is the entire file if this is important

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true, 
    "noImplicitAny": false, // this is probably not really clever... https://blog.atomist.com/declaration-file-fix/
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're not using the angular wrapper, remember to call Plotly.purge() in ngOnDestroy in order to avoid memory leaks, see https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlypurge and https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/blob/d24a5f5c6bf7aeaf618d7e01bc79da07ce6670fb/projects/plotly/src/lib/plotly.component.ts#L130.

Answer (score 0):

The following setup worked quite nicely for me:

1. Install types via npm install --save-dev @types/plotly.js
2. Connect plotly.js library with this type declaration in tsconfig.js (I figured this works for any type of include, both npm installed node modules and locally included ones.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",    
    "paths": {
          "assets/scripts/plotly.min.js": [
            "../node_modules/@types/plotly.js"
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note that base url needs to be set if paths is used. This assigns my plotly lib  to the types definition. Works beautifully.